# Sharepoint 2010 + vs2010 + search for Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint, list, search, textbox

I'm just start using Sharepoint 2010 so this question is difficult for me.

The question is - I have Sharepoint List with some information (for example - Surname, Name, Address). What I want to do: I want to make a web part (textbox + smth else). In my textbox I want to start typing some phrase (let's say I start typing "Jo"), and my List must return all items that starts with "Jo". Can you help me with some links or advises, how can I do this?

And another question is - how can I show resulting List? Is there some containers in Sharepoint 2010 like gridview or listview?

Comment: Our product [MatchPoint](http://www.colygon.com/technical-features) - an application framework for SharePoint - provides [these features out-of-the-box](http://www.colygon.com/technical-features/sharepoint-web-parts/data-grid-web-part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all of this using SP 2010's client object model. You can make asynchronous calls, to avoid doing postbacks. Here's a good starting point: [SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx).

If you go for server-side development, you can use the [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx) or even just a standard Grid View to show the results.